# turn back shapefile from pandas to geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have these shapefiles:

```
q=gpd.read_file(a.shp)
df=gpd.read_file(b.shp)
final = pd.merge(df, q, on=['FID_buffer'], how='inner')
#out= a certain directory
final.to_file(out)
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_file'

I want after the join to export it back as shp

I tried with spatial join in geopandas but it said something with crs was wrong that's why I did with pandas but I can't export it.

```
final = gpd.sjoin(df, q, how="inner", op='intersects')
```

which gives:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

Comment: Yes, that where I read about the second way which gives the crs error. How can I do what I am trying here and work? Thanks

Comment: As  I get it, I think is by attribute just like I did it with pandas but be able to export later.

Comment: When you join by attribute (so a merge with pandas), the result will be a pandas DataFrame and will have two columns with geometry data (one of each original GeoDataFrame). Therefore, you need to explicitly convert it back to a GeoDataFrame specifying which geometry column should be used: `GeoDataFrame(final, geometry='name_of_geometry_name')`

Comment: Thanks. If you want make an answer about it and add more details. So people can  see it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When joining 2 GeoDataFrames by an attribute (so a merge with pandas and not a spatial join, which can certainly be sensible for a given application), the result will be a pandas DataFrame and not a GeoDataFrame.
It will also have two columns with geometry data (one of each original GeoDataFrame), and you will need to decide which of those columns you want to have as the 'active' geometry column (i.e. the column that is used for the spatial methods called on that GeoDataFrame).

Therefore, you need to explicitly convert it back to a GeoDataFrame specifying which geometry column should be used:

```
GeoDataFrame(final, geometry='name_of_geometry_name')
```

Comment: I asked the question. I wasn't on my pc and I created another account which I don't have anymore. I upvoted though. I wanted to ask is it safer to do spatial join with geopandas instead? How can you escape the crs problem with spatial join? Thanks

Comment: It is not "safer" or "less safe" to do a spatial join with geopandas instead of a standard join in pandas. It is a different operation, and so it depends on your use case and desired result which one of the two you should use.

Comment: The error message about the crs indicates that the `df` you pass to the `sjoin` method is not a GeoDataFrame, but a normal pandas DataFrame. A spatial join needs two GeoDataFrames.

Comment: BTW, I think you can ask for a password reset for an account (as long as you have access to the email-adress)

Comment: So because one of the shapefiles lost the geometry column, it turned the geodataframe to just dataframe? Thus it could not perform the spatial join.